# IOS/Objective-C: Get index of string in array of strings case-insensitive

Tags: ios, case-insensitive

I am trying to find when a string matches (case insensitively) a string in an array of strings and, in turn, get the index number.  There is a good way to do this when case is the same.  Alternatively, the code below is able to tell me whether a case-insensitive match exists.  However, I can't get it to tell me the index when the match is case-insensitive.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
- (NSUInteger)findIndexOfWord:(NSString *)word inString:(NSString *)string {
      NSArray *substrings = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

     if ([substrings indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
     return (BOOL)([obj caseInsensitiveCompare:word] == NSOrderedSame);
     }] != NSNotFound) {
     // there's at least one object that matches term case-insensitively
         int index = [substrings indexOfObject:word]; //if a case-insensitive match returns -1.

         return index; // Will be NSNotFound if "word" not found

     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *word = @"YOLO";
NSArray<NSString *> *items = @[ @"hi", @"yolo", @"swag" ];

NSUInteger idx = [items indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj caseInsensitiveCompare:word] == NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)idx);
```

> **indexOfObjectPassingTest:** Returns the index of the first object in the
>   array that passes a test in a given block.

Hope it helps. Be aware, idx can be NSNotFound.